# Configure CoffeeScript Cake test to output in plain text

Tags: coffeescript, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins for continuous integration testing

I'm running a Cake test

My output includes formatted text like the following:

```
✗ [31m[1mErrored[22m[39m » [1m14[22m honored ∙ [1m1[22m errored ∙ [1m13[22m dropped
```

Can I add a configuration parameter in my Cakefile which disables this formatting and outputs only plain text?

What options do I have for disabling this formatting and outputting only plain text?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript, but if you install the [AnsiColor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) for Jenkins, that output will be displayed correctly, i.e. with coloured highlighting.